# Client-side only web applications

Tags: javascript

I am seeing more and more applications that seem as though they are entirely written in JavaScript see (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/) for an example and view the source. As you will see there is no source code except a call to a series of JS files. The app works as though it's still a website though and seems to use the HTML5 history API to alter the address on the fly.

Anyone know much about this sort of technology/design patterns, know some good starting points or examples of their own? I have seen things like Sproutcore and Cappuccino but they seem very different to the way in which the Chrome web store has been built.

I'm looking to use it with frameworks like ASP.NET MVC 3 and CakePHP.

Comment: Google+ (http://google.com/+) also has the most ridiculous source you've ever seen. The *only* explanation I can come up with for this style of source is obfuscation to the max; I wouldn't call it a *pattern* at all.

Comment: I doubt it's written entirely in JS. More likely it's just generating a basic DOM then using AJAX to populate things.

Comment: Google+ like many other "Google" things are written in Java -- their source is not human readable .

Comment: Matt: Many Google properties, including (probably) Google+ are written using the Closure javascript compiler (http://code.google.com/closure/). The code it emits is both obfuscated and compressed, but the compiler enforces a lot of nice conventions including type-checking in javascript (based on annotations).

Answer (score 0):

Alot of Googles projects are developed with Google Web Toolkit. It's a framework for building Javascript apps in Java.

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/

Comment: GWT is slow, bloated and a horrible abstraction.